# Spring Service and RestTemplate Client always Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: spring, rest

My POJO:

```
public class Product {

    String name;
    int price;

    public Product(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }   
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class RstController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/getProductPost2", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json"})
    public Product getProductPost2(@RequestBody Product p){
        System.out.println(p.getName());
        return p;
    }
```

My Client, using JUnit(I've tried all the lines commented, the same error everytime):

```
public class RestTemplatePostTest {

    @Test
    public void testee(){

        String url = "http://localhost:8443/ShoppingCartSpringMVCSpringDataHibernate/rest/getProductPost2";

        Product  p = new Product();
        p.setName("produs");
        p.setPrice(22);
        String json = "{\"name\":\"pen\",\"price\":10}";

        HttpEntity<Product> request = new HttpEntity<Product>(p);
        RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();

        rt.postForObject(url, json, String.class);
        //rt.postForObject(url, p, String.class);
        //rt.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, Product.class);
        //rt.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
        //assertEquals("produs",p2.getName());
    }
}
```

When I'm using POSTMAN, it works.
I haven't found any other option on the internet and it's been 2 days since I'm trying to do this . Any opinion or tutorial is more than welcomed.

Edit1: Also, a simple GET also doesn't work,but it works in browser or in POSTMAN.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getProductGet", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getProductGet{
    return "hello World!!";
}

@Test
    public void testGet(){

        String url = "http://localhost:8443/ShoppingCartSpringMVCSpringDataHibernate/rest/getProductGet";

        RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response= rt.getForEntity(url, String.class);

    }
```

When in debug mode, it stops in my breakpoint when called by browser or POSTMAN, but it doesn't get there when using rest template. 
Perhaps something to do with the fact that I'm using Spring security?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your request has a wrong data type which server can not parse and thus can not reply.

Since you are sending a POST request with JSON Content-Type, your `Product` must be JSON-encoded.

To do that, you need to add a json converter so modify your code to some thing like this:

```
    RestTemplate rt= new RestTemplate();
    rt.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    Product recievedProduct = rt.postForObject(url, p, Product.class);
```

Don't forget to add the jackson dependency.